# Do rails rake tasks provide access to ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, task

I am trying to create a custom rake task, but it seems I dont have access to my models. I thought this was something implicitly included with rails task.

I have the following code in lib/tasks/test.rake:

```
namespace :test do
  task :new_task do
    puts Parent.all.inspect
  end
end
```

And here is what my parent model looks like:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end
```

It's a pretty simple example, but I get the following error:

```
/> rake test:new_task
(in /Users/arash/Documents/dev/soft_deletes)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Parent

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 437):

Figured it out, the task should look like:

```
namespace :test do
  task :new_task => :environment do
    puts Parent.all.inspect
  end
end
```

Notice the  `=> :environment` dependency added to the task

Comment: what does this syntax mean? it's assigning `new_task` to the current environment? what is the current value of `:environment`? google is not helping.

Comment: @scoarescoare :environment here is the dependency, so when running `new_task`, load the environment (load your models) first, and then run new_task.

Comment: @scoarescoare you can check [custom rake doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks),the first example will tell you

Comment: how to achieve same thing in Sinatra ?

Comment: model name has to follow with all and it does not work without it like TodoList.all.each not TodoList.each idk why it seems working?

Comment: why is creating a namespace required? I wrote a rake task without namespace and I could not access records from my database.

Answer (score 17):

you might need to require your configuration (which should specify all your required models etc)

eg:

```
require 'config/environment'
```

alternatively you can just require each seperately, but you might have environment issues AR not set up etc)

Comment: This will work, but it will break rake in general!  After adding this change, try rake -T without a DB available.  rake -T should happily provide a list of rake tasks without needing access to the DB!

Comment: After doing this you will find that any other rake tasks that requires initializing the application (i.e. rake assets:precompile) will fail with "rake aborted! Application has been already initialized".

Answer (score 14):

When you begin writing your **rake** tasks, use a generator to stub them out for you.

For example:

```
rails g task my_tasks task_one task_two task_three
```

You'll get a stub created in lib/tasks called `my_tasks.rake` (obviously use your own namespace.) Which will look like this:

```
namespace :my_tasks do

  desc "TODO"
  task :task_one => :environment do 
  end  

  desc "TODO"
  task :task_two => :environment do 
  end  

  desc "TODO"
  task :task_three => :environment do 
  end  

end
```

All your rails models etc. will be available for the current environment from within each task block, unless  you're using the **production** environment, in which case you need to require the specific models you want to use. Do this within the body of the task. (IIRC this varies between different versions of Rails.)

Comment: Couldn't you just say that `environment` is required as a dependency and then say the syntax rather than encouraging the OP to rely on "magic" utilities that don't even use any magic?

Answer (score 7):

With the new ruby hash syntax (Ruby 1.9) the environment will be added like this to the rake task:

```
namespace :test do
  task new_task: :environment do
    puts Parent.all.inspect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Generate task using below command (namespace with task name):

```
rails g task test new_task
```

Use below syntax to add logic:

```
namespace :test do
  desc 'Test new task'
  task new_task: :environment do
    puts Parent.all.inspect
  end
end
```

Run above task using below command:

```
bundle exec rake test:new_task
```

or

```
 rake test:new_task
```

Answer (score 3):

The :environment dependency is quite correctly called out, but rake still may not know about other gems that your models depend on - in one case of mine, 'protected_attributes'.

The answer is to run:

```
bundle exec rake test:new_task
```

This guarantees that the environment includes any gems specified in your Gemfile.