# Rails 3 rake task can't find model in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

My simple rake task, stored in `lib/tasks/items_spider.rake` runs just fine in development. All it does is call `spider!` on the `Item` model.

```
namespace :items do
  desc "Spider the web for data, hoorah"
  task :spider => :environment do
    Item.spider!
  end
end
```

I have the `:environment` task as a dependency, so everything works just fine. However, when I add `RAILS_ENV=production`, I hit errors, both on my local server and the production server:

```
$ rake items:spider RAILS_ENV=production --trace
(in /home/matchu/Websites/my-rails-app)
** Invoke items:spider (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute items:spider
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Object::Item
/home/matchu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
/home/matchu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.22/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
/home/matchu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@rails3/gems/rspec-expectations-2.0.0.beta.22/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in `const_missing'
/home/matchu/Websites/openneo-impress-items/lib/tasks/items_spider.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/matchu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
[...trace of how rake gets to my task...]
```

This just seems odd to me. Apparently the models have not been loaded correctly. I'm on Rails 3.0.3, though development on this app started back when Rails 3 was in beta. How can I go about debugging this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Reaching a bit here, but have you tried moving the RAILS_ENV declaration to the start of the command?

Comment: Where is the `Item` model kept? The usual spot?

Comment: @Ryan: mhm. `app/models/item.rb`

Comment: Going to bed now; it somehow only just now occurred to me to test with other models. Will try that tomorrow :) Thanks!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/876411/52499).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Contrary to running your application in production, a Rake task does *not* eager load your entire code base. You can see it in [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb):

```
module Rails
  class Application
    module Finisher
      # ...
      initializer :eager_load! do
        if config.cache_classes && !$rails_rake_task
          ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:before_eager_load, self)
          eager_load!
        end
      end
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

So *only* if `$rails_rake_task` is `false`, will the application be eager-loaded in production. And `$rails_rake_task` is set to `true` in the `:environment` Rake task.

The easiest workaround is to simply `require` the model that you need. However, if you *really* need all of your application to be loaded in the Rake task, it is quite simple to load it:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

The reason all of this work in development is because Rails autoloads your models in development mode. This also works from within a Rake task.

Comment: Did a bit more research, and it turns out that this is somehow related to my app being marked as threadsafe in production, which it didn't actually occur to me to mention. I'll look a bit more into how to address that exact issue. Thanks!

Comment: `$rails_rake_task` is no longer defined in recent versions of rake or rails, but you can still manually set `$rails_rake_task = true` in your Rakefile

Comment: Rails.application.eager_load! is not working in my rake task. It says application_controller.rb not found. I followed the trace and within active_support/dependencies.rb#search_for_file autoload_paths is empty. However in my Application.rb file I explicitly add the controllers to the autoload_paths. What's happening?

Comment: This solved my issue where I was getting `NameError: uninitialized constant ...` when running a rake task in the production environment only (dev worked fine). Adding `Rails.application.eager_load!` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 37):

In your environment/production.rb, you should add the following:

```
config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task
```

It solved the problem for me.

(Note: this should be added AFTER the config.threadsafe! call)

Comment: why is that even needed? This looks like a bug, no?
If it loads the :environment, it should load the models too

Comment: Is there a better way in rails 4?

Comment: `$rails_rake_task` is no longer defined in recent versions of rake or rails, but you can still manually set `$rails_rake_task = true` in your Rakefile

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me in Rails 6.0.3.2.

I was trying to configure the rake file `task :foo do ... end.` Instead it should've been `task foo: :environment do ... end`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found another one: I was developing on windows, deploying to Heroku. The web app and rails console worked fine, but rake tasks and even direct require could not load the model. Turned out I had absentmindedly created the model file as `Model.rb` instead of `model.rb` - system dependent case sensitivity.