# Rails uninitialized constant in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rake-task

I have a weird problem. In development this problem does not exist, but in production rake throws this error message at me "uninitialized constant Program"

The "Program" is an active record model, and it's there, it's in the schema file and it's in the app/model folder.

I execute it like this rake import:xml RAILS_ENV=production. What could be the problem? Below is the full stack trace

```
rake import:xml RAILS_ENV=production --trace
(in /usr/mobloom/www/htdocs/remindertest)
** Invoke import:xml (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute import:xml
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Program
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/usr/mobloom/www/htdocs/remindertest/lib/tasks/import_assets.rake:18
/usr/mobloom/www/htdocs/remindertest/lib/tasks/import_assets.rake:9:in `each'
/usr/mobloom/www/htdocs/remindertest/lib/tasks/import_assets.rake:9
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Line 18: program = Program.find(:first, :conditions => ['programident = ?', broadcast['PROGRAMME']['PROGRAMME_ID']])

Comment: Can we see a stacktrace please?

Comment: what do you rake task ? Can you put it here ?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
require 'app/models/program'
```

or if you need most of your models

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

Rake doesn't eager load your models.

See a good explanation here [Rails 3 rake task can't find model in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300240/rails-3-rake-task-cant-find-model-in-production)

Comment: This isn't rails 3, but 2.3.8, and this is only an issue on my prod environment, not in development

Answer (score -1):

You've probably forgotten to depend your task on :environment.

```
task :xml => :environment do
  ...code here...
end
```

EDITED! Probably not the right answer look at the answer with the eager loading.

Comment: -1 because if you look at the posted log you can see environment is loaded

Comment: Yes I realize that, thats why i edited my post and upvoted yours. Would you like me to delete my answer and downvote myself in addition?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as stated by David, the environment is being loaded