# Rake task can't find model on gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

My rake task can't find a model comes from a gem on a production environement but works on development.

I read this topic a lot of times (and many others) : 
[Rails 3 rake task can't find model in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300240/rails-3-rake-task-cant-find-model-in-production)

But I can't solve the problem.

Rake finds my other classes on app/models without any problem. It miss only 'RapnsNotification' from the gem "rapns". This class is load during the scenario.

This is my task :

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_record"
require "awesome_print"
require 'rake'
require 'rapns'

task :delete_user => :environment  do |t, args|
  print "Deleting completely user..."
  print Rails.root
  user_id = ENV["id"]
  @user = User.find(user_id) 
  STDOUT.puts "Do you really want to delete #{@user.firstname} #{@user.lastname} (#{@user.email})? (y/n)"
  input = STDIN.gets.strip
  if input == 'y'
    DeleteUserScenario.call!(@user) unless @user.nil?
  else
    print "deleting user stopped"
  end
end
```

This is the commande I do (if it could help) :

```
RAILS_ENV=devcenter bundle exec rake delete_user id=111
```

And this is my error :

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Notification::RapnsNotification
...bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:111:in `compute_type'
...bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you simple require the gem in your rake task at the top? require 'rapns'?

Comment: It's already done. Sorry for this mistake on my code. I'm updating it.

Comment: I assume all of these gems are available to the `devcenter` environment in your Gem file?