# Rails.application.eager_load! not working in rake script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, activesupport

I'm trying to call Rails.application.eager_load! in my rake task.
This is the error that I'm getting.

```
LoadError: No such file to load -- application_controller
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `each'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:470:in `each'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:470:in `eager_load!'
/home/jkoehms/TECC/tecc/lib/tasks/populate.rake:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:659:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:659:in `each'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:659:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:452:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in `load_tasks'
/home/jkoehms/TECC/tecc/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/jkoehms/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>
```

Looking into this further, I found that the autoload_paths was empty in my active_support/dependencies.rb file. This should have been taken care of by the :set_autoload_paths initializer in engine.rb. However the initializer is never called. When I byebug into eager_load and manually call it myself the error goes away. Why isn't the initializer being called?

UPDATE:
when I call Rails.initialize! it then works. But this seems like a hefty call. Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: The Rails.application.eager_load! was being called before my rake task started, by moving it into the rake task it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer about the reasons here: [Rails 3 rake task can't find model in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300240/rails-3-rake-task-cant-find-model-in-production)

I have a similar problem before:

```
app@LacosteDev-aws:~/app/current$ rake resque:preload QUEUE=* --trace
** Invoke resque:preload (first_time)
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:preload
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ResourcesController
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/qor-c93ebb95226f/widget/app/controllers/resources/widget_controller.rb:2:in `const_missing'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/qor-c93ebb95226f/widget/app/controllers/resources/widget_controller.rb:2
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `eager_load!'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `eager_load!'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `to_proc'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:412:in `eager_load!'
/media/ebsdisk/app/releases/20150630071432/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/tasks.rb:61
```

I just add `config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task` to `config/environments/production.rb` it works for me.
You can also set `$rails_rake_task = true` in your Rakefile manually.