# Saving the output from a ruby script into my rails database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a small ruby script that generates an array like the one below:

```
{:title=>"Lorem ipsum",
 :category=>["Lorem ipsum"],
 :items=>
  ["Lorem ipsum",
   "Lorem ipsum",
   "Lorem ipsum"],
 :process=>
  ["Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error."]}
```

How can I run that script in order to save the output into my rails database?

Comment: What Models do you have in your app? are these items stored under a different model?

Comment: @adam: I have 3 models.
Model "A" => Title and Process
Model "B" => Items
Model "C" => Category

Comment: I think you mean "hash", not array. you say model A holds title and process, but then you use an array for process. On the other hand, what's the nature of the problem, this seems pretty straighforward AR usage, did you peruse the Rails guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of guessing... you can write this is a rake task:

```
WeDontKnowWhichModelHere.create!({
 :title => "Lorem ipsum",
 :categories => [Category.new(:name => "Lorem ipsum"), ...],
 :items => [Item.new(:name => "Lorem ipsum"), ...],
 :processes => [Process.new(:name => "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error")],
})
```

Comment: Where in the project should I call my script.rb in order to gather the output? Thank you

Comment: @antonio. If this is a code outside the request cycle, you can write a rake task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876396/do-rails-rake-tasks-provide-access-to-activerecord-models, http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks