# Rails Rake Task - Access to model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I would like to define a Ruby (1.9.2)-on-Rails(3.0.5) rake task which adds a user to the User table. The file looks like this:

```
#lib/tasks/defaultuser.rake
require 'rake'
namespace :defaultuser do
  task :adduser do 
    u=User.new
    u.email="bob@example.com"
    u.password="password"
    u.save
    u.errors.each{|e| p e}
  end
end
```

I would then invoke the task as

```
> rake defaultuser:adduser
```

I tested the code in the :adduser task in the Rails console, and it works fine. 
I tested the rake task, running only

```
print "defaultuser:adduser"
```

in the body of the task, and it worked fine.

However, when I combined them, it complained, saying

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User
```

I tried a

```
require File.expand_path('../../../app/models/user.rb', __FILE__)
```

at above the namespace definition in the rake file, but that didn't work. I got

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

What do I need to do so that I have the same access to the User model class in the Rake task that I have in the Rails console?

Comment: Similar question: [Do rails rake tasks provide access to ActiveRecord models?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876396/do-rails-rake-tasks-provide-access-to-activerecord-models

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You're close :)

```
#lib/tasks/defaultuser.rake
require 'rake'
namespace :defaultuser do
  task :adduser => :environment do
    ...
  end
```

Note the use of :environment, which sets up the necessary Rails environment prior to calling the rake task. After that, your User object will be in scope.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh! I was close. I don't get the syntax though.

Comment: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial This tutorial sheds more light on the problem, and also shows a nice way to parameterize the rake task.

Comment: @JayGodse That link is now unfortunately broken