# rake aborted! undefined method `map' for :name:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm trying to pass arguments to a Rake task and access my model as mentioned in "[How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)" and "[Do rails rake tasks provide access to ActiveRecord models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876396/do-rails-rake-tasks-provide-access-to-activerecord-models)".

However adding `=> :environment` to this code:

```
require 'rake'

namespace :genre do
    desc "Add a genre"
    task :add, :genre_id, :name => :environment do |t, args|
        puts args.name  
    end
end
```

Gives me this error when I run the task:

```
rake genre:add['1','Abc']
rake aborted!
undefined method `map' for :name:Symbol

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If I delete `=> :environment` it works just fine.

---

UPDATE:

TRACE:

```
rake --trace genre:add['1','Abc']
rake aborted!
undefined method `map' for :name:Symbol
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:254:in `set_arg_names'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:29:in `define_task'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:310:in `define_task'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:32:in `task'
/private/var/www/html/someapp.com/subdomains/someapp.heroku.com/someapp/lib/tasks/genre.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:207:in `in_namespace'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:102:in `namespace'
/private/var/www/html/someapp.com/subdomains/someapp.heroku.com/someapp/lib/tasks/genre.rake:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/private/var/www/html/someapp.com/subdomains/someapp.heroku.com/someapp/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like your syntax is off. Try:

```
task :add, [:genre_id, :name] => :environment do |t, args|
```

Comment: First: works beautifully. Second gives: WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.

Comment: dont use the :needs... just use task :foo, [:arg1, :arg2] => [:bar]