# How to store cron job results in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, cron, storage

I need to store data from a cron job in Ruby on Rails so that my controllers can still access it. I'm not too sure what the best way is to do this. By the way I'm a Ruby on Rails newb, so perhaps what I'm asking is extremely simple.

Comment: Save it to the database?

Comment: That was the first idea that I had, was assuming that there is a more efficient process though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby (there is a revised version, but you have to pay $9 aprox. per month for pro videos).

You can make a task or a runner so you can access to ActiveRecord and store the data into some model.

For runners in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner
For tasks: http://erik.debill.org/2011/12/04/rake-for-rails-developers

Also, if you use tasks (which I recommend) watch this entry: [Do rails rake tasks provide access to ActiveRecord models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876396/do-rails-rake-tasks-provide-access-to-activerecord-models)

Answer (score 1):

One way to store the results of you cron job is the create a controller with basic authentication if you care about the security of your results.

See [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html).

So after you save your results from you cron say to `/tmp/myresults`, you can post via

```
curl -d @/tmp/myresults  http:/myrailsapplcaition.com:3000:/path_tomypost_method
```